How to show the connections between a class with a list of interface implementators, a concerete interface implementation and the interface?
I have a situation from the picture, MyTimer contains a list of Updatable, and PlayerBulletUpdatable is one of the potential elements, alongside many defined in lambda clauses.
What is the correct way of modeling this in UML?
I have almost no knowledge of UML, and the internet didn't help. 
This one is not ok


Using the shared aggregation is not wrong per se. But according to UML 2.5 it has no defined semantics.You need to provde that along with the model.

So what turned out to be correct is just a dependancy between MyTimer and Updatable, with the arrow on the side of Updatable.

Your elements will look like this:

In the diagram we have depicted:

Two classes: MyTimer and PlayerBulletUpdatable;
The interface Updatable;
Relations: aggregation with multiplicity zero or more and realization.


You're using the shared composite notation. This is, as you know, a notation without defined meaning. (see p. 112 of UML 2.5.1)

@qwerty_so thanks for your addition. But the question does not allow us to clarify the connection (I relied on the indications of this aspect in the model shown in the question when choosing). And the corresponding clarification would not affect the code being developed corresponding to the model.
